# How can I dynamically populate morris.js charts from results sent via my controller?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, morris.js

im using the latest codeigniter framework and im working on a database search feature that searches our databases based on a form input, the results are sent to the view in an array contailing all the data from the search generated in the model.

Im trying to use this data to populate morris.js charts but ive hit a wall. I can extract the data I need using php but how would I use that data to populate the charts?

This is the basic chart js:

```
new Morris.Donut({
// ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
element: 'donutEg',
// Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
// the chart.
data: [
    {label: "Positive", value: 7},
    {label: "Negative", value: 26},
    {label: "Pending", value: 786},
    {label: "Contact Clinic", value: 243},
    {label: "Unspecified", value: 1}
],
// A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
ykeys: ['value'],
});
```

I want to populate the results using these php variables:

```
<?php $pos = 0; $neg= 0; $pen = 0; $cont = 0; $misc = 0;
    foreach ($chart as $item) {
        if ($item['result'] === 'Positive') {
            $pos++;
        }
        elseif ($item['result'] === 'Negative') {
            $neg++;
        }
        elseif ($item['result'] === 'Pending') {
            $pen++;
        }
        elseif ($item['result'] === 'Contact the Clinic') {
            $cont++;
        }
        else{$misc++;}
        $res = array("Positive"=>$pos, "Negative"=>$neg, "Pending"=>$pen, "Contact the Clinic"=>$cont, "Misc"=>$misc);
    }; echo 'Positive Results: ' . $pos . '<br />' . "Negative Results: " . $neg . '<br />' . "Pending Results: " . $pen . '<br />' .
        "Contact Results: " . $cont . '<br />' . "Misc Results: " . $misc . '<hr />'; ?>
```

How would i go about using the array '$res' to populate the chart using the named keys as the charts labels and the corresponding value as the value?

Cheers

** UPDATE **
Using this code as suggested by @nando i get only one segment: Positive with a value of NaN (althhough values are numbers, Positive = 7)

```
new Morris.Donut({
    // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
    element: 'donutEg',
    // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
    // the chart.
    data: [
        {label: "Positive", value: "<?php echo $res['Positive'] ?>"},
        {label: "Negative", value: "<?php echo $res['Negative'] ?>"},
        {label: "Pending", value: "<?php echo $res['Pending'] ?>"},
        {label: "Contact Clinic", value: "<?php echo $res['Contact the Clinic'] ?>"},
        {label: "Unspecified", value: "<?php echo $res['Misc'] ?>"}
    ],
});
```

** Further Update **
i have the following JSON array:

```
{"Positive":7,"Negative":26,"Pending":786,"Contact the Clinic":242,"Misc":2}
```

How do I go about assigning these values to my chart?

Answer (score 0):

You can do  it whith `<?php echo ?>` in the javascript side:

```
new Morris.Donut({
    // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
    element: 'donutEg',
    // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
    // the chart.
    data: [
        {label: "Positive", value: <?php echo $pos ?>},
        {label: "Negative", value: <?php echo $neg ?>},
        {label: "Pending", value: <?php echo $pend ?>},
        {label: "Contact Clinic", value: <?php echo $cont ?>},
        {label: "Unspecified", value: <?php echo $misc ?>}
    ]
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for a speedy reply. I tried this and initially It produced a blank graph, after some playing im now getting an empty graph with values NaN, the values are numbers  though, if i echo them i get 7 for positive etc, any ideas?

Comment: Ok, sorry, for the Donut you need to take off the ykeys, i edit my answer

Comment: Cheers but still no joy. I get the same output f Positive: NaN using this

Comment: Ok, try not tu use the array, so change the '$res["Positive"]' for $pos and so on for all the values

Comment: tried that haha, everything I seem to try makes my chart vanish